# Remove "Search Everything" box

Tags: 2013, search

How can I remove this search box from the sidebar on my site? It appears everywhere and for some reason doesn't stay in the bounds of the sidebar. We don't really have a use for it...

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

UPDATE:

So far, in response to the answer below, I have tried adding the following to the site master page just before the closing head tag:

```
#SearchBox { display: none; }

<style type="text/css">#SearchBox { display: none; }</style>
```

I tried to wrap these changes into a content editor web part to see if that will help the CSS to activate. Doesn't appear to work.

I now have the default master page again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can remove it from Master Page.

**Using CSS**

1. Edit Master page
2. Add following just before `</head>`

   ```
   #SearchBox { display: none; }
   ```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Do I need other stuff like <style/> tags? Sorry, I don't actually know any CSS.

Comment: Yes. `<style type="text/css">#SearchBox { display: none; }</style>`

Comment: Hmm...I used exactly that and it didn't work. Does it maybe have some kind of a refresh time on it?

Comment: No. Using browser developer tool check the ID of the search box is `SearchBox`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589512(v=vs.85).aspx#SelectByClick

Comment: Yeah, that's the right ID. I tried going a little higher ("searchInputBox") but that didn't help either...

Comment: Please update the question with the changes you did so far on the master page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19286/discussion-between-amal-hashim-and-user3380049).

Comment: These changes are supposed to go in v4.master right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom master page  and if you have publishing feature enabled. You need to check the option Reset master page inhering all sites and sub sites" under master page.

Also try switching the master page to default and then to custom and try the scenario.